# Reactive transform function not behaving as anticipated

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

A reactor transform function I created does not give the same result when I extract the individual steps and execute them separately.

I have DTO record that contains a List of type Price.

```java
public record CarrierDto(MetaData metaData, List<Daily> dailySeries) {

    public record MetaData(String name, String information) {};
    public record Daily(String date, Integer price) {};
}
```

I want to extract from a `Mono<CarrierDto>` a `Flux<Daily>` and then transform that to `Flux<Price>`.

```java
@Table("price")
public record Price (
        @Column("p_date") String date,
        @Column("p_price") Integer price) {
}
```

To do this transformation I have this function:

```java
static Function<Mono<CarrierDto>, Flux<Price>> transform = carrierDtoMono ->
            carrierDtoMono.map(CarrierDto::dailySeries)
                    .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
                    .map(daily -> new Price(daily.date(), daily.price()));
```

However when I try to use this function only one price is given upon subscription. If I extract each individual step and execute ALL prices are provided. For example with this test class:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TestMain {

    static Function<Mono<CarrierDto>, Flux<Price>> transform = carrierDtoMono ->
            carrierDtoMono.map(CarrierDto::dailySeries)
                    .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
                    .map(daily -> new Price(daily.date(), daily.price()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final CarrierDto dto = new CarrierDto(new CarrierDto.MetaData("Test", "Test information"),
                Arrays.asList(new CarrierDto.Daily("2023-01-01", 100),
                        new CarrierDto.Daily("2023-01-02", 101),
                        new CarrierDto.Daily("2023-01-03", 102),
                        new CarrierDto.Daily("2023-01-04", 103)));

        System.out.println("Using Transform function.");
        Mono.just(dto)
                .transform(transform)
                .subscribe(price -> System.out.println(String.format("Date: %s Price: %d", price.date(), price.price())));

        System.out.println("Without transform function.");

        final Mono<List<CarrierDto.Daily>> monoDailySeries = Mono.just(dto).map(CarrierDto::dailySeries);
        final Flux<CarrierDto.Daily> dailyFlux = monoDailySeries.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
        final Flux<Price> priceFlux = dailyFlux.map(daily -> new Price(daily.date(), daily.price()));

        priceFlux.subscribe(price -> System.out.println(String.format("Date: %s Price: %d", price.date(), price.price())));
    }
}
```

Gives the result:

```
Using Transform function.
Date: 2023-01-01 Price: 100
Without transform function.
Date: 2023-01-01 Price: 100
Date: 2023-01-02 Price: 101
Date: 2023-01-03 Price: 102
Date: 2023-01-04 Price: 103
```

Why is the result different?

Comment: How do you know it's the second `subscribe` output? Both are running at the same time so it can be output of the first as well

Comment: @IgorArtamonov fair point but comment out the second subscription. The point is the outputs are different. this is just a test example.

Comment: I see, just saying it's not clear from the output which subscription is producing it, because it can be any. I've checked it and you're right, it's the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `transformer` in `Mono` produces a new `Mono`, i.e., requesting only the first item from the Publisher.

Internally it has:

```
Mono<V> transform(...) {
   ...
   from(transformer.apply(this))
}
```

I suggest to start with Flux (or convert Mono to Flux). Like for your example:

```
static Function<Flux<CarrierDto>, Flux<Price>> transform = carrierDtoFlux ->
        carrierDtoFlux.map(CarrierDto::dailySeries)
                .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
                .map(daily -> new Price(daily.date(), daily.price()));

Flux.just(dto)
        .transform(transform)
        .subscribe(price -> System.out.println(String.format("Date: %s Price: %d", price.date(), price.price())));
```